# Getting import module error in Lambda function even after adding a layer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

[image]I’m trying to use Pandas and PyArrow library in my lambda function. I created a “Python” folder locally, downloaded all library files from PyPi in that folder, zipped it and created a layer. But while testing , it’s still giving me “No module named Pandas.

Python - 3.9
Folder structure for layer :
Python/pandas, pandas-2.0.3.dist-info , numpy , numpy-1.25.0.dist-info , pytz , pytz-2023.3.dist-info

I successfully added the layer in my Lambda function but it’s still giving me error while testing.

Comment: Please share python version, aws lambda version, tree structure of zip file so we could give options on how to solve it.

Comment: Python version- 3.9 . 
I have added folder structure in question. All the libraries are inside a folder named Python

Answer (score 0):

So even after adding the zip file as layer it didn't work then there is a high chance of improper directory structure.

Previously, I faced the same issue multiple times. So I prefer to follow the structure as shown below.

> Datetime.zip/layer/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/*

Here I'm trying to import Datetime library. So I first created a folder named layer that follows the above folder structure and in the site-packages I installed the library using pip. Then zip the layer folder and rename in to your convenience.

Please change the python3.9 folder name to which python that you are using.